# When are piped inputs necessary in Ruby? (|x| x.to_s)

Tags: ruby, lambda, shorthand

I have recently found out that the piped inputs that many ruby methods use are not necessary some of the time, but this seems to be inconsistent. For example, this line creates an array of strings for yesterday, today, and tomorrow:

```
DateTime.now.instance_eval{[prev_day, to_datetime, tomorrow]}.map{|d| d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}
=> ["06/20/2016", "06/21/2016", "06/22/2016"]
```

As you can see within instance_eval, there is no piped input, and the function simply assumes that the methods are being called on DateTime.now. But if I try to apply the same idea to the map method:

```
DateTime.now.instance_eval{[prev_day, to_datetime, tomorrow]}.map{strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}
NoMethodError: undefined method `strftime' for main:Object
```

Suddenly it is trying to use the method on main?

My question is why did this work in the first method and not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs for `instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval):

> Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (obj). In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing, giving the code access to obj's instance variables and private methods.

`instance_eval` on the one hand is very special, because you call it on a *instance* and it was explicitly build to run the block in the context of *instance*. Therefore the method can always assume that the context of `self` is always the instance on which `instance_eval` was called.

`map` on the other hand is different: In your example you call it on an *array*, but the block should run on *each object within the array*, therefore you need to pass different objects to the block in each iteration.

Comment: Ah ha! Going back through my code it is always instance_eval that this is working on. OK, makes sense now.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with `instance_eval` at all. A more straight forward example would be `[1,2,3].map {chr}` and `[1,2,3].map {|x| x.chr}`. The result is the exact same.

Comment: @Mike: I cannot reproduce your example: `[1,2,3].map {chr}` results in 
`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'chr' for main:Object` on Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: You have just reproduced it. That's precisely what the original question was asking about.

Comment: Sorry @Mike, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you mean that your two examples are both result in the same output and read it as a counter-example to what I said.

Comment: Oops now I see why my wording was confusing. I should not have said "The result is the exact same." But yeah I was just pointing out that the issue in the original question was not actually related to `instance_eval`.

Answer (score 0):

> When are piped inputs necessary in Ruby? (|x| x.to_s)

Piped inputs are necessary when a block is passed to any method with a `yield` that has arguments.

In your specific case `instance_eval`'s yield does not have arguments, whereas `map` does. The problem you're having has nothing to do with `instance_eval`. If `yield` expects you to pass a variable along but you don't do so then it is forced to assume that `self` is the main object. And that is exactly what is happening in your second example with `map`. Take a look at this example.

```
def yield_to_integer # yield integer 5 to the block
  yield 5
end  

yield_to_integer {|int| int.chr} # successfully run .chr() on the Integer 5
#  => "\x05"
yield_to_integer {chr} # fails to run .chr() because it is not defined on Object
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `chr' for main:Object
```